# Should I involve EEOC if I haven't been promoted for over 25 years?

Tags: united-states, promotion, government

I've been working for Veterans Affairs Medical Center for over 30 years. My last promotion was 25 years ago (from [GS 4 - GS 5](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-systems/general-schedule/), step 10) and that one turned out to be a dead end job. According to coworkers and other employees, I am good at my job, and very helpful. As matter of fact, some of them got promoted with my help. However, I've gone so long without a promotion.

Now, here is where I think maybe the [U.S. Equal Employment Opportunity Commission (EEOC)](https://www.eeoc.gov/overview) need to be involved. Lab Manager is an Foreign African Black man and most of the employees that he either hired or promotes will get special rate (higher) pay. While I (American Black woman) get belittled for being the next lower grade until they (supervisor and manager) need me because I know and would help do the work of other higher grade employees. Most employees praise me for helping them but still I'm not getting an offer for a  promotion. However, if I'm late all the time, or make (in my opinion) a tiny mistake, that will be a reason not to give a promotion.

Comment: "Most employees praise for help them but still I'm not getting an offer for a promotion."  Are you able to apply for a new position/promotion within your company?

Comment: Do you believe that your lack of a promotion is a result of something under the purview of the EEOC? If so, then by all means reach out to them.

Comment: Have you ever, in the 33 years you've worked there, talked to your manager about promotion and what it would take to get one? Have you met the requirements to be promoted to the next level?

Comment: You may want to consider not using your real name, in case your co-workers or boss see this.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment " if I'm late all the time, or make to me tiny mistake, that will be a reason not to give a promotion".  Are you in fact "late all the time"?  That does seem like it would be a reason to not promote you.

Comment: It is very strange that you did not get any promotion for over 33 years. Have you considered getting a new job elsewhere ? New jobs usually give you a higher salary than getting promotions at old companies.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with federal pay in the United States: [General Schedule Classification and Pay](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-systems/general-schedule/), [Within Grade Increases](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-administration/fact-sheets/within-grade-increases/).

Comment: The one question on Workplace where editing the question is actually detrimental to understanding the broader context.

Comment: If you want to change your name, ask the mods, they can do that for you. If you're using your real name, you don't want your fellow employees to google your name and suddenly land on this page. As to being late, if the other employees being promoted are late the same amount as you, then there may be a case for discrimination. Aside from talking to your union, ask your personnel file from HR, and start keeping your own records. Put an app on your phone that logs your ins and outs. Log how frequently you're late. Log how frequently others are late. Start accumulating documentation (if possible).

Comment: "Lab Manager is an Foreign African Black man and most of the employees that he either hired or promotes will get special rate (higher) pay." - I am very familiar with how pay in the federal government works, what you describe does not make sense, the only reason these individuals are being paid more is because they are being hired into a position with higher pay.  The amount of people who are prompted in their own position, to reasons primarily connected to budgets.  Do you have evidence these individuals were given grade increases and were the same grade as you were?

Comment: By the way if you are late "all the time" you might focus on the issues your manager has identified, because grade increases, are typically merit based when you are in a general schedule position.

Answer (score 13):

The Department of Veteran Affairs has a [Master Agreement](https://www.va.gov/LMR/docs/Agreements/AFGE/Master_Agreement_between_DVA_and_AFGE-fin_March_2011.pdf) (see also [all resources for Resources for the VA-AFGE Master Agreement](https://www.va.gov/lmr/agreements.asp)) with the [American Federation of Government Employees](https://www.afge.org/). If you believe you've been improperly passed over for promotion, you should go talk to your union.

I recommend reading "ARTICLE 23 - Merit Promotion" from the Master Agreement, which outlines what's supposed to happen regarding promotions.

I think you should do this, rather than going directly to the EEOC, because:

1. You union rep likely has experience in this area.
2. If your manager has violated the labor contract, you probably don't even have to get into whether it was due to discrimination in order to get relief.